# How do you merge two cells if another cell contains certain strings?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want B1 and C1 to merge if A1 is either a,b,c but not if it is anything else.

I think the merging function is
`sheet.getRange('B1:C1').merge();`
but I am not sure how to check what the value of A is and if it is one of the strings that trigger the merging.

To clarify the merging bit, I mean two cells becoming one cell which spans over two columns.

Comment: Can you give a detailed example of what do you expect to happen if a merge is performed? Some might not even be sure what a merge is, so it would be good if you detail that, too.

Comment: I have edited the main post, but to clarify what I mean by merge, I mean the two cells become one cell which spans over two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood what you want exactly but the code below merges cells B1 & C1 if value in A1 meets one of the 3 conditions you choose.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
  if(range.getA1Notation()!='A1'){return};
  if(range.getValue()=='a' || range.getValue()=='b' || range.getValue()=='c'){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1:C1').merge();
  }
}
```

It runs automatically when a cell is edited and does nothing if the cell is not A1.

---

EDIT : since it appears from your comments that you wanted it to work for all the rows, here is a version that will merge cells in col B and C in any row if column A in this row meets the condition.

```
function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var range = e.range;
  if(range.getColumnIndex()!=1){return};
  if(range.getValue()=='a' || range.getValue()=='b' || range.getValue()=='c'){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRowIndex(),2,1,2).merge();
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try to run the code, this error comes up: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: You can not test it from the script editor since e is indeed undefined in this case, try it by editing the sheet cell directly

Comment: Ah, thank you. It works for A1, B1, C1, but when I change it to A2, B2, C2, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You didn't ask for a function that works for the whole column... is that what you need ?

Comment: If possible please. Also, the code works when I make a new sheet, but not in an existing sheet. Finally, is it possible to have it so when the cell is edited after the merge occurs, and does not have one of the strings, the cells are unmerged?

Comment: see edit please. it should work in existing sheets as well, there is no reason it would fail. As for your other request it is of course possible, I suggest you try it yourself now that you see the general idea.... don't forget SO is not a "code supermarket where everything is free"

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure why it isn't working on existing sheets.  Could it be to do with the data in column A being validated?

Comment: no, it should not interfere... do you have any other function that is triggered by an onEdit ? or a conditional formatting somewhere ? btw, please consider accepting the answer as it gives an answer to the initial post. thx

Comment: I don't have any other onEdit's, but I do have conditional formatting in the sheet. I used to have it in column B and C, but removed it, but it still doesn't work. On a side note, I managed to get do unmerge the cells with Range.breakApart()

Comment: Well done!  And thx for accepting :-)  look at the execution transcript to see why it fails on you old sheet

Comment: The error was that I couldn't merge cells through an existing filter. I didn't need it so I just turned it off. Thank you very much for all of your help!